# MongoDB Lat Long issue

Tags: mongodb

While I am running this query

{"geo" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$centerSphere" : [ [ 37.7561438 , -122.4325682] , 0.07583417593528817]}}}

I am getting following error

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException: point (37.7561,-122.433) must be in earth-like bounds of long : [-180, 180], lat : [-90, 90]

I am not sure why this error is occurred. Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: seems like lat is out of bounds... it says right there in the error that lat should be a value between -90 and 90.. clearly your lat is over that as it is -122

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the lat and lon turned

Please try:

```
{"geo" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$centerSphere" : [ [ -122.4325682, 37.7561438] , 0.07583417593528817]}}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have found and fixed it.